# How to sum a field according a condition from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables 'Course', 'Members' and 'Courses_members' table. I want to sum the course fee only if the field 'paid' in courses_members table is 1.

```
**Course table:**
Id
Course_name
Course_fee

**Members table:**
Id
Name

**Courses_members table:**
course_id
member_id
paid
```

I am new to laravel so I don't know how to do this. I appreciate it if anyone can help.

Comment: check documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns

Answer (score 0):

```
$courseIds = Courses_members::where('paid',1)->pluck(course_id);
$course_fe = Course::whereIn('id',$courseIds)->sum('Course_fee');
```